# how to take views.py file from app to project/urls.py file

Tags: django

I created a project in django.in that from app/views.py i have to call the functions to mention in the project/urls.py .But its not accepting.

mentioning the names from app/views.py to project/urls.py

Comment: can you show the code? what you did

Comment: from django.shortcuts import render
from django.http import HttpResponse
from rest_framework import viewsets

from .serializers import PersonSerializer, SpeciesSerializer
from .models import Person, Species


def hello(request):
    return HttpResponse("this is from projectname views")
def hai(request):
    return HttpResponse("this is hi")

Comment: the above one is views.py file in the demoapp.I want to call these functions in project/urls.py file.but it is not showing the demoapp as module

Comment: Is it really hard to post your code example to under your question?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.